# "[object Object]" showing in input field with bootstrap3-typeahead and tagsinput

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

When a tag is selected, the tag is added correctly but the text [object Object] is appended in the input box. (See the below image)

I am using Bootstrap 3, JQuery, Bootstrap3-typeahead, and bootstrap-tagsinput (All the most recent versions)

The form is in a modal window.

[image: tag_error]

Here is the code:

```
jQuery('#banner_geo_locations').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeahead: {
        displayKey: 'text',
        source: function (query) {
            return jQuery.get("http://dev.marijuanaweeklycoupons.com/?action=ajax|cityStateSsearchTags&PageSpeed=off&q=" + query);
        }
    }
});
```

Ajax looks like:

```
[{"value":"2908762","text":"Dixon Corner, AL"},
{"value":"2956030","text":"Dixon Corner, ME"},
{"value":"3008251","text":"Dixon Corner, PA"},
{"value":"2931983","text":"Dixon Crossroads, GA"},
{"value":"3017149","text":"Dixon Crossroads, SC"},
{"value":"2959449","text":"Dixon Estates, MD"},
{"value":"2959450","text":"Dixon Hill, MD"},
{"value":"2993971","text":"Dixon Landing, NC"},
{"value":"2908763","text":"Dixon Shop, AL"},
{"value":"2938722","text":"Dixon Springs, IL"}]
```

See it in a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgaxuyda/7/)**

Comment: The JSFiddle's broke. Problems making a request to that source.

Comment: @JayMee It's not broken, it's just not allowed to make an external request due to security restrictions.

Comment: Here's a version that doesn't use an Ajax call to an external resource https://jsfiddle.net/rgaxuyda/7/

Comment: I don't have a clue with this one. +1. Stumped sorry.

Comment: My guess is that something's broken in the minification

Comment: Whatever it is, it's most definitely not your code OP. Try the 'non-minified' version. If it's still happening, step through it yourself.

Comment: I am going to try and replicate it without the minification in jsfiddle. Thanks @jcuenod.

Comment: Well, just using the libraries as they as distributed in jsfiddle resulted in the same problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/rtmqnoL0/1/

Comment: You're right, it's not minification but it is your version of the library - I have answered the question. Your solution is still relevant though.

Answer (score 3):

It is a library issue.

Adding the below solves the issue:

```
afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
```

As such,

```
jQuery('#banner_geo_locations').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeahead: {
        displayKey: 'text',
        afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
        source: function (query) {
            return jQuery.get(current_web_root + "?action=ajax|cityStateSearchTags&PageSpeed=off&q=" + query);
        }
    }
});
```

See jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rgaxuyda/11/

Comment: How do you know it's a library issue? Of course the afterSelect callback will correct the problem but what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lucky Edward, it works, thanks.

```
<script>
    var elt = $('#inputSoftwareList');
    elt.tagsinput({
        itemValue: 'value',
        itemText: 'text',
        typeahead: {
            source: function(query) {
                return $.getJSON('cities.json');
            },
            afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); }
        }
    });

</script>
```